# Extend ext4 partition past 16TB Debian

Tags: debian, raid, ext4

Im running debian jessie 8.6 on my server and i have extended my raid array past 16TB... 19TBish total.

however i cant extend the partititon since its EXT4 32 instead of ext4 64.

```
resize2fs: Size of device /min/disk is too big to be expressed in 32 bit
```

Is it possible to convert the partition without loosing all data?

This is kinda the only solution ive found: https://askubuntu.com/questions/779754/how-do-i-resize-an-ext4-partition-beyond-the-16tb-limit/779755

i just want to make sure i go along the path which gives me the greatest chance of succeeding

Comment: That doesn't look unreasonable. Do you have a specific concern about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading https://askubuntu.com/questions/779754/how-do-i-resize-an-ext4-partition-beyond-the-16tb-limit/779755 it sounds like the only viable solution if you want to increase the size of the filesystem.

Personally I would find this solution to be too cumbersome and error prone and I would opt to create a separate partition utilising the extra space on the raid. I also prefer to use XFS, however ext4 serves just fine.

If you use ext4 make sure to set "-O 64bit" just in case.

Note this quote from the above link:

> Backup whatever you cant lose. Always. Also note, this size of
>   filesystem WILL be harmed by regular disk errors, so configure a RAID
>   for guaranteed integrity.

It seems like another motivation for using a separate partition.